# correct way to import mydart.dart file in main

Tags: dart, import

In my dart project `projectxyz`, I have a dart class declared in in `myclass.dart`.  In `main.dart`, Android Studio gives two ways, both work, but I did not understand what are the pros and cons of each method:

`import 'myclass.dart';`

or:

`import 'package:projectxyz/myclass.dart';`

What is the difference in these two approaches?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how the `main` file itself is invoked (and where it's located).
I'll assume the `main.dart` library is inside the `lib/` directory, because otherwise you wouldn't have the two options for importing `myclass.dart`.

If you invoke the main file with a `file:` URI, then the relative import of `myclass.dart` will also be imported with a `file:` URI. Since Dart uses the import URI to distinguish different libraries, if someone else imports `myclass.dart` using a `package:` URI, then it will be treated as two different libraries introducing different classes with the same name.

It used to be that running `dart lib/main.dart` would treat that as a `file:` URI. The Dart parser has gotten smarter about that, and now it recognizes that an entry point library in a `lib/` directory should have been a `package:` URI, and replaces the entry point URI with `package:projectxyz/main.dart`.

After that, it makes no difference whether you use `myclass.dart` or `package:projectxyz/myclass.dart`.

Answer (score 1):

Really, there is no difference between the two. Saying `import 'myclass.dart'` is high-level sugar for `import 'package:projectxyz/myclass.dart';`.

On the other hand, `import 'myclass.dart'` is easier to read and understand, and generally looks better. It also decreases confusion as to where exactly your code is being imported from, as anybody who reads this statement knows to look for the file elsewhere in your project. Because of this, you should try to use this form wherever possible.